# collection route of get type redirects to show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have defined a routes in collection method of get type but its redirecting to show action of controller rather that merge_fields action

```
resources :notification_templates do 
    collection do
      get :merge_field_keys
    end
  end
```

so its path is `/notification_templates/merge_field_keys`

now the `notification_templates_controller` is redirecting it to show method and taking `merge_field` as id.

```
class NotificationTemplatesController < ApplicationController

  def merge_field_keys
  end

end
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be something in your routes file that's matching somewhere higher up in the file. Can you post your routes.rb?

Answer (score 0):

Your method name is `merge_field_keys` where as your route says `merge_fields`. Try changing one of them

```
resources :notification_templates do 
  collection do
    get :merge_field_key
  end
end
```

OR

```
class NotificationTemplatesController < ApplicationController
  def merge_fields
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry @kumar its a mistake while posting question the method name and route name is same actually

Comment: And you're going to `/notification_templates/merge_field_keys` path and not `/notification_templates/merge_fields`, right?

Comment: Can you show us your part of your routes file where you've written routes for `notification_templates`?

Answer (score 0):

What you said can't happen, if you run `rake routes` you will find 
`/notification_templates/merge_field_keys` is defined before `/notification_templates/:id`, and when you request from server Rails start to match to the first Path which is `merge_field_keys` and when all not match it will call `show` action and pass whatever after `/notification_templates` as `id` param.

Possibly you defined `resources :notification_templates` twice and you have it above what you mentioned, run `rake routes` and make sure, and in case you don't even need show action you can do:

```
resources :notification_templates, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy] do 
  collection do
    get :merge_field_keys
  end
end
```

and you can also remove from this array whatever you don't use `[:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]`

Answer (score 0):

Try These:

redirect_to :controller => 'notification_templates', :action => 'merge_field_keys'